# How to reinstall or downgrade PHP on Centos

Tags: centos, php, yum

Having used the atomic repository for a couple of years to update my Centos (6.8) and Plesk 12, I required an update to PHP that wasn't yet available.

I added the remi repos and updated PHP to 5.5.38 to discover a few errors in PHP. Rather than trying to debug this and many others (and because an update to PHP 5.6 is now available) I would like to reinstall PHP from atomic.

Is this just a simple case of yum remove php-* and reinstalling from Atomic or is there any issues I am likely to encounter. Don't want to break it all.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it is not good practice to mix and match different repositories. Anyway, try the following:

- with the `remi` repo enabled, do a `yum remove php*` (pay **big** attention to the list of to-be-removed packages to be sure no critical packages are uninstalled)
- disable the `remi` repo and enable the `atomic` one
- do a `yum install php`
- restart apache with `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 2):

When php 5.5 is install from "remi-php55" repository, simpler way is to update to php 5.6 from "remi-php56", following the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/):

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php55
yum-config-manager --enable  remi-php56
yum update
```